# Changing apache user from www-data to another user

Tags: apache-2.2, security

I am wondering the security risk of changing apache run user from www-data to another.

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/envvars

Configs:
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

I have change to:
export APACHE_RUN_USER=myusername
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=myusername
```

My main reason for doing this is because I have ssh keys setup for myusername and it also makes managing new files created by apache a lot easier since they are no longer belonging to www-data.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the running Apache process has read access to `myusername`'s files, you should be fine.

If Apache doesn't have read permissions to `myusername`'s files, anything you put in the docroot as `myusername` will be unable to be served.

Comment: Yes, I'm putting all my code under /home/myusername/projectfolder

Comment: As long as you only have one user for your domains, this should be fine. It would be problematic if you had other users on the system with their own domains.